# how to svn version control of a project contains both code and data files

Tags: svn

I am thinking about how to appropriately version control a project related to Natural Language Processing, with script programs (Perl, Shell, etc) manipulating text files. The scripts usually read text data files as input, do some processing, and output the results again as text files. So there are lots of code and data files, all in text format.

Obviously, I only version control code files, because data files may be of large size. And I need to maintain branches of the code, to experiment with different methods.

(1) My current solution of version control is to mix code and data files in the same level of a single directory "proj":

code1, ..., codem, data1, ..., datan

When working with branches, I need to check out all files in "branchi" right under "proj", but not in a "branchi" sub folder, in order to keep the above "flat" directory structure.

The pros of my current solution are minimal directory transition overhead. Since code and data are in the same directory, calling scripts and reviewing results involves least amount of "cd":

script1 data-in data-out

vi dataout

The cons are when the number of code and data files grows , it looks messy facing a long list of files in "proj" folder.

(2) Another way is to put code and data under different directories:

"proj/src" and "proj/data".

The pros and cons are just opposite to solution (1). The pros are I can get cleaner directory structure. The cons are I need to do lots of directory transitions, when calling the scripts or reviewing results:

script1 ../data/data-in ../data/data-out

vi ../data/data-out or cd ../data; vi data-out

if in src folder. so the extra parent path of the data files "../data" brings lots of directory transition hassles, especially when one needs to do lots of quick experiments and checkings of results.

Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the second way - separate projects with their own data/src underneath.

You can easily use scripts, symlinks, and aliases to make it convenient to work with whatever you wind up with.

But if your directory layout in Svn is a giant ball of chaos, you'll find it very hard to disentangle when it gets too messy.

So your layout might look like this:

```
/sources/
    /project1/
        script-for-proj-1
        other-stuff-for-proj-1
        data-for-proj1              --> /data/dataset24
    /project2/
        script-for-proj2
        other-stuff-for-proj-2
        data-for-proj2              --> /data/dataset23
```

Here, everything in `/sources` lives in Subversion.
Each project directory has symlinks out to the data directory it needs.
But all data actually lives in `/data`, and archived/maintained using
whatever tools make sense for that.

The other advantage of this system is that while the data isn't versioned,
the symlinks are, so as your projects need different inputs you can track
what they're using.

Comment: Interesting. One way to avoid cd, according to your suggestion, is to create symlinks for all scripts in the data folder, then I can work on data folder as if code and data were in the same folder.

Comment: But my above method is still not perfect. It separates code part for easy version control. However, it still mixes the symlinks to code and data together, which could look messy. Are there ways to better separate code and data and yet require minimal directory transitions, especially when both the code and data could be have multi-level directories?

Comment: @Fashandge - see edits for a complete answer

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. Sounds good, it makes svn easy and clean. But I still need to face jungle of scripts and symlinks to data in a same folder. On the other hand, if I don't put symlinks of data in the same folder, I pay the cost extra of directory changes.